# Calling SendAysnc in ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I would like to send out some mail as a response to a page hit.  I would like the page not to wait for the mail to be sent, hence SendAsync.  In testing, it turned out that "<%@ Page Async="true" ...%>", e.g.,

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CallbackHandler.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyWebRole.CallbackHandler" Async="true" %>
```

was needed.  However, I'm still getting a 500 error, even though the SendAsync is called and email is sent.  Here's what I was using.  In the interim, I have reverted back to "Send" (which works with Async="true")

```
sc.SendCompleted += ((sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        newPayment.transmitted = db.GetSQLDate();
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
    else
    {
        newPayment.exceptions = e.Error.Message + Environment.NewLine + e.Error.StackTrace;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
});
sc.SendAsync(mm, null);
```

What is the right way to stage this?

Comment: Post your code please, and explain what exception is getting thrown on which line.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend posting it to some kind of a queue and processing the queue in a separate thread of even another service.